# AWS Cognito login for Swagger-UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, authorization, amazon-cognito

We publicly host our API documentation at `ourcompanyhostname.com/docs`. This has been extremely useful for us to make API requests, and has replaced Postman for us. The way we currently authenticate here is:

1. Open Swagger UI
2. Press the "Authorize" button
3. Copy an API key from the API keys page of our app
4. Paste it into the "Available Authorizations" window

[image: Swagger available authorizations]

Our authentication is handled via AWS Cognito and the AWS Amplify hosted UI. Is there any way that we can plug that authentication in here? My ideal workflow would be:

1. Open Swagger UI
2. Press Authorize
3. Login with AWS Cognito
4. Swagger is authorized

Is there a good way of doing this? Is it possible to create custom authorization functions in Swagger-UI so I can write a Cognito plugin? Or, is there a more standard route e.g. via oauth2 to plugin a login provider such as Cognito?